# Как сделать простой сервер на Python работающий как автономно, так и через apache?

Tags: python, ajax, apache

Необходимо создать простой одностраничный сайт для тестовых целей. На странице необходимо иметь возможность делать AJAX запросы к серверу. Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом реализовать самым простым и быстрым способом инфраструктуру сервера? Необходимо учитывать, что сервер будет запускаться как на локальной машине не техническим специалистом, так и на общем тестовом сервере. На локальной машине не технического специалиста нет какого–либо специального ПО. На сервере используется apache2, а также настроено окружение для django–проектов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самым простым способом реализовать указанное будет использование встроенного python HTTP–сервера на локальной машине и простого WSGI–приложения на сервере. При создании структуры проекта необходимо учитывать, что при работе через WSGI статические файлы лучше отдавать напрямую через apache.

Предлагаемая структура проекта будет следующей

```
server.py
static/
| - index.html
| - m/
    | - styles.css
    | - scripts.js
    | - img/
```

В этом случае, мы сможем одинаково работать с файлами проекта. В html/css коде ссылки на статические файлы будут выглядеть следующим образом

```
/m/scripts.js
```

Конфигурация apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.ru
        DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/site/root/"
        ServerName mysite.ru

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIDaemonProcess mysite
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/site/root/server.py 

        Alias /m/ /path/to/my/site/root/static/m/

        <Directory /path/to/my/site/root/static/m/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/mysite_error.log"
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/mysite_warning.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

В конфигурационном файле для сервера мы казали, где находится наш WSGI скрипт (`WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/site/root/server.py`). Предлагается использовать тот же скрипт и для локального сервера. Также мы добавили псевдоним для `/m/` (`Alias /m/ /path/to/my/site/root/static/m/`). Таким образом, все что остается – сделать папку `static` рабочей директорией для локального сервера, а apache автоматически сам будет обрабатывать ссылки на файлы.

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import os
import sys

PORT = 8000
AJAX_ENPOINT_URL = "/ajax/endpoint"
DOCUMENT_ROOT = "/path/to/my/site/root/"

# Обработчик локального сервера.
class CustomHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    # Обрабатываем GET–запрос к серверу. 
    # Если запрос к приходит по известному нам URL, формируем ответ.
    # Если мы не знаем URL, предлагаем стандартной библиотеки обработать его.
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == AJAX_ENPOINT_URL:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','application/json')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("My ajax response") 
            return
        else:
            SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.chdir("./static/")
    httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), CustomHandler)
    print "Serving at port", PORT
    httpd.serve_forever()
    quit()

def get_index():
    f = open(DOCUMENT_ROOT +'/static/index.html', 'r')
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
    return data

def application(environ, start_response):
    output = ""
    status = "200 OK"
    content_type = "text/plain"
    path = environ.get('PATH_INFO', None)

    if path == "/" or path == "index.html":
        output = get_index()
        content_type = 'text/html'
    elif path == AJAX_ENPOINT_URL:
        content_type = 'application/json'
        output = "My Ajax response"

    if output == "":    
        status = "404 Not Found"
        output = "Not Found"

    response_headers = [('Content-type', content_type),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Для запуска сервера на локальной машине, достаточно перейти в корень проекта и выполнить команду

```
python server.py
```

В случае запуска на сервер, необходимо добавить конфигурацию apache в папку конфигураций и перезапустить его.